# Modal value is binding to last cell in table instead of selected one

Tags: html, blazor, webassembly

I have a table with a bunch of rows, and for some cell in the row I provide the option to open a modal and manually change the value, or choose something from the dropdown.

When I choose from the dropdown, the cell gets updated how it should be. However, if I try to let them use the modal and enter a value, then the value they entered gets bound to the last row in the table. I do not understand why this is happening.

Here is the relevant code.

Table:

```html
@foreach (Item item in items)
{
    <tr>

        <td>@item.Name</td>
        <td>
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <BlazoredTypeahead SearchMethod="search.something"
                                    @bind-Value="@item.Amount"
                                    Debounce="500"
                                    tabindex="0">
                    <SelectedTemplate Context="amt">
                        @amt
                    </SelectedTemplate>
                    <ResultTemplate Context="amt">
                        @amt
                    </ResultTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <div class="blazored-typeahead__result no-border-top" @onclick="showAmountModal">
                            Other...
                        </div>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </BlazoredTypeahead>
                <DropdownOtherInputModal Name="Amount" @ref="amountModal" @bind-Data="@item.Amount"></DropdownOtherInputModal>
            </div>
        </td>
```

Modal:

```
<BSModal @ref="modal" IsCentered="true">
    <BSModalHeader OnClick="@onToggle">Enter @Name</BSModalHeader>
    <BSModalBody>
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                 <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">@Name</span>
            </div>
                <InputText type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" @bind-Value="input"/>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm global-btn-submit global-modal-btn-align" @onclick="onSave">Submit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm global-btn-cancel global-modal-btn-align" @onclick="@onToggle">Cancel</button>
    </BSModalBody>
</BSModal>

[Parameter]
public string Name { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public string Data { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public EventCallback<string> DataChanged { get; set; }

public string input { get; set; }

BSModal modal;

public void onSave()
{
    Data = input;
    DataChanged.InvokeAsync(input);
    modal.Hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to make a copy of the item inside the loop and then use the LocalItem to stamp out the row like this

```html
@foreach (Item item in items)
{
    Item localItem = item; 
    <tr>

        <td>@localItem.Name</td>
        <td>
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <BlazoredTypeahead SearchMethod="search.something"
                                    @bind-Value="@localItem.Amount"
                                    Debounce="500"
                                    tabindex="0">
                    <SelectedTemplate Context="amt">
                        @amt
                    </SelectedTemplate>
                    <ResultTemplate Context="amt">
                        @amt
                    </ResultTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <div class="blazored-typeahead__result no-border-top" @onclick="showAmountModal">
                            Other...
                        </div>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </BlazoredTypeahead>
                <DropdownOtherInputModal Name="Amount" @ref="amountModal" @bind-Data="@item.Amount"></DropdownOtherInputModal>
            </div>
        </td>
```

otherwise all items  get a reference to the last item.

Comment: That isn't solving the problem unfortunately. I think part of the problem is the way I am opening the modal. In the file with the table code, I have a reference to the modal and open it using that. But if I add the button to open the modal in the modal component itself, I can update the correct row fine. However, if I do that then I can't put the button to open the modal in the dropdown because it will lose focus and close.